# PHP constructor can't access outdside class variable

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I have trouble using a variable defined in an external file, to be used in a class constructor.

basic.php:

```
<?php
$config = array(
'sqlHost'       => 'localhost',
'sqlUser'       => 'root',
'sqlPassword'       => '',
'sqlDatabase'       => 'test',
);

$temp= "test";
?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
require_once('basic.php');

class foo{
    private $bar;

    function __construct() {
        $this->bar = new mysqli($config['sqlHost'],$config['sqlUser'],$config['sqlPassword'],$config['sqlDatabase']);
    echo $temp;    
    }
}
$tester = new report;
?>
```

I always get back that $config is not defined, however, $temp works.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `public function __construct( $config ) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject it with [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (good)
or
use the [`global` modifier](http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) (bad)...

Comment: Or just pass it as parameter in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// ... your class

public function __construct(array $config)
{
     // set class properties but check first if config is valid
}
```

or put your config in an own class and inject this one into your foo class

```
<?php

// ... your class

public function __construct(Config $config)
{
     // set class property
}
```

On a sidenote:
Since this seems to be for a database connection be sure to only create one object for a request. Some people use a Singleton pattern for that but I don't recommend it. At the end it is your code so only you can decide how your solution will look like.

Answer (score -2):

in test.php

```
<?php
require_once('basic.php');

class foo{

global $config;   // add this line.

    private $bar;

    function __construct() {
        $this->bar = new mysqli($config['sqlHost'],$config['sqlUser'],$config['sqlPassword'],$config['sqlDatabase']);
    echo $temp;    
    }
}
$tester = new report;
?>
```

and it will work then